# Export huge database (40GB)

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I have database that is big 42GB (and I need all tables), Two tables have more than 10gb.

When i do :

```
mysqldump -h host -u username -ppassword dbname > export.sql
```

Server in most cases crash, or I get message after some duration "MySQL server has gone away".

I use docker with nginx, ubuntu 16.04, php...

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout
Maybe you could check variables

Answer (score 1):

To dump the database and gzip it at the same time, use the following. This will prompt you for your password.

```
mysqldump -u [USERNAME] -p [DBNAME] | gzip > [/path_to_file/DBNAME].sql.gz
```